# I can't use my fingerprint sensor in my device ideapad-5-15ARE05

Tags: lenovo

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 27c6:55a2 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix FingerPrint Device can't install driver of it

Comment: Do you have a driver to install? What version of Ubuntu are you using? What kernel are you running? These are just some of the details you need to add to the question with edit. Please do not use comments to add info.

Comment: The same issue with Ideapad 5 i7